# lektor menu with links to child pages only, parents toggle submenu, without links

Tags: menu, jinja2, submenu, lektor

I need to generate a menu that lists all pages (like the [sitemap sample](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/guides/sitemap/)) but if a page has childs it should become only a toggle for its submenu, not linking to any page. Only the innermost childs will be pages.
E.G.:

- about (link)
- portfolio (no link - only toggle)

  - work01 (link)
  - work02 (link)
- contacts (link)

As I said, the summentioned sample creates and links a page also for "portfolio".
My site is here [andrearicci.it](http://andrearicci.it/projects/fendi-velabro/) (subpage) and the menu item "projects" now toggles the submenu, but I can't get rid of its link - so I had to format an unwanted 'projects summary' page.
On that page the menu is

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="projlist">
    {% for project in site.get('/projects').children %}
      <li{% if this == project %} class="active"{% endif
        %}><a href="{{ project|url }}">{{ project.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I wish an automatic solution, that could work also adding other page groups (e.g. paintings/web design/whatever) without the need of changing it every time.

Is it maybe more a question about Jinja other than Lektor?

Thank you for any help.

A.R.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: just test if the page contains children, if so - do not link the page.

The test should be as easy as

```
{% if project.children %}
  {# no link #}
{% else %}
  {# link #}
{% endif %}
```